# Correlated residuals in estimated model

Tags: time-series

I am working with the weekly data set from the Keeling Curve which can be accessed here: http://scrippsco2.ucsd.edu/data/atmospheric_co2/mlo (weekly in-situ CO2 data).

I selected an SARIMA model, but it fails the Ljung Box test with p < 0.05.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to find a better model?

I have tried to decrease the number of parameters, but the test still fails...

Answer (score 0):

Use 51 weekly indicators and/or 11 monthly indicators to deal with deterministic structure that might be in your data. Eliminate 1 of the weeks in a leap year to deal with the 53 week effect . Add arima structure as necessary and also deal with pulses by adding pulse indicators where necessary. This should enable your creation of uncorrelated residuals. If not you might need to segment your data as your model parameters may have changed over time and/or deal with an error variance that may not be constant over time.

EDITED AFTER RECEIPT OF DATA IN ORDER TO PROVIDE GUIDANCE ABOUT DATA THAT REQUIRES.

1) trend change point detection
2) error variance change point detection
3) arima structure
4) time trend variable
5) deterministic seasonal dummies representing fixed weekly effects

here is the equation [image] and here [image] with a residual plot here [image] and acf residual plot here [image]

The error variance detection was suggested here [image]

The model presented here provides a much better looking acf of the residuals than your pure ARIMA model BUT it is not perfect .

this is an example of a series whose 52 period seasonality dependence is deterministic rather than stochastic(ARIMA) and multiple break points (I_L) are found. The large sample size (3112) yield a (VERY APPROXIMATE) standard error of the acf to be 1/sqrt(3112) which is less than .02 which often yields false acf tests on the residuals.

Comment: The ACF plot shows an annual seasonal effect that has not been removed.  Your recommendations look like a particularly onerous, non-parsimonious, and generic way to deal with that.

Comment: The possible utilization of dummy indicators should be considered as a complement to memory structure. Only the data knows for sure . The idea that i suggest possible structure doesn't automatically suggest to the final parsimonious structure incorporating memory and deterministic (latent) structure as necessary and sufficient. The acf of lag 52 might be the result of unwarranted seasonal differencing.

Comment: You seem not to be responding to the question.  Like many of your answers, this reads like a generic plug for the approach implemented in your software rather than as a thoughtful response to the question that was posted.  Please stay on topic.

Comment: the user asked "Does anyone have any suggestions on how to find a better model?" I answered ... My suggestions are a possible way ( no software referenced here ! ) .

Comment: BTW, I'm sorry you read my initial comment as being "unfriendly or unkind."  I felt a duty to inform readers about the nature of your recommendations: a comment about *what you post* must be distinguished from any kind of personal commentary.

Comment: OK . I will actually study this weekly series and report on the results. What I should have reflected on is that weird acf values for model residuals can often be the result of either insufficient differencing OR unwarranted differencing OR a very poor ARIMA model OR the presence of latent deterministic structure like seasonal dummies .

Comment: Right: that's the kind of insight we have come to expect from your better posts!